# Turbulence parameterization from gravity - fluid dynamics correspondence

Tags: gravity, fluid-dynamics, specific-reference, ads-cft, turbulence

I`m looking for a nice introductary reference that explains how the turbulence coefficient or any kind of turbulence parameterization (in view of applications to atmospheric turbulence for example) can be derived from the gravity - fluid dynamics correspondance, such that even I can get it. I mean, if something like this exists ...

I`m basically quite familiar with the hydrodynamic part (NS equation, etc) of this correspondance whereas about the other side I feel a bit more shaky ...

I`m finally looking for a citable reference, but any "reasonable" source (slides of a talk, video, ect) that explains how a turbulenc coefficient / parameterization can be obtained would be welcome and appreciated.

Edit

To clarify what I mean, relevant papers for the topic are for example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5502), [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2451), and jep [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5780) one linked to by Mitchell.

Comment: Perhaps I am not familiar enough with the topic, but what do you mean by "correspondence?" Are you asking about the phenomenology of turbulence in a fluid when a gravitational field is present (convection?), or about something else?

Comment: @kleingordon see http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5780

Comment: I`ve once seen the slides of a talk by Johanna Erdmenger, where she derived a turbulence coefficent, but I cant find it now and I`d like to have a citable paper about this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the critical exponents of the velocity
correlation functions? First of all, I don't think they 
have been derived using fluid/gravity (this is a very 
difficult problem), at best the problem was mapped onto
a different problem. There was a series of papers by Oz and 
others about incompressible (and compressible) Navier-Stokes 
some years ago, see for example http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3638, 
http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4999, 
http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3574. There are also somewhat more
handwaving efforts like http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3254.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will study these papers to see if they contain what I need.